# How to position a circle at a specific point?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently learning JS and I'm doing this canvas exercise, the task is to "draw" circles on a rectangle by the parameters that the user enters (x and y for positioning the first circle, the radius of the circles and the amount of circles), each circle's x should grow by 1 each time and be positioned accordingly.
The thing is I just can't position the circles no matter what I do! I'm pretty sure it's related to my CSS(which I suck at).
Does anyone know how to position the circle at a specific point?

```js
var container = document.getElementById('container');

var rectangle = document.createElement('div');
rectangle.setAttribute('id', 'rectangle');
container.appendChild(rectangle);

var style = document.createElement('style');
style.innerHTML = "#rectangle {height:300px; width: 400px; background-color: #e1c699; position: relative;}";

document.head.appendChild(style);

var formElement = document.createElement('div');
formElement.setAttribute('id', 'form');

var xInput = createInput("x", "Please enter x");
var yInput = createInput("y", "Please enter y");
var radius = createInput("radius", "Please enter radius");
var numOfCircles = createInput("numOfCirc", "Please enter number of circles");

formElement.appendChild(xInput);
formElement.appendChild(yInput);
formElement.appendChild(radius);
formElement.appendChild(numOfCircles);

var submitBtn = createBtn('submit', 'Submit');
formElement.appendChild(submitBtn);

container.appendChild(formElement);

submitBtn.onclick = function() {
  var numOfCirc = document.getElementById('numOfCirc').value;
  var raidus = document.getElementById('radius').value;
  var x = document.getElementById('x').value;
  var y = document.getElementById('y').value;

  for (var i = 1; i <= numOfCirc; i++) {
    drawCircle(x, y, raidus, i);
    x = parseInt(x) + 1;
  }

}

function drawCircle(x, y, raidus, id) {
  var circle = document.createElement('div');
  circle.setAttribute('class', 'circle');
  circle.setAttribute('id', id);

  var style = document.getElementsByTagName('style')[0];
  if (id == 1) {
    var circleSize = ".circle {height: " + radius.value + "px; width: " + radius.value + "px; background-color: #555; border-radius: 50%;}";
    var position = "#" + id + " {position: absolute; left: " + x + "px; top: " + y + "px;}"
    style.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', circleSize);
    style.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', position);
  } else {
    var position = "#" + id + " {position: absolute; left: " + x + "px; top: " + y + "px;}"
    style.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', position);
  }
  rectangle.appendChild(circle);
}

function createInput(id, displayName) {
  var input = document.createElement("input");
  input.setAttribute("id", id);
  input.setAttribute("placeholder", displayName);
  return input;
}

function createBtn(id, displayName) {
  var btn = document.createElement("button");
  btn.setAttribute("id", id);
  btn.innerText = displayName;
  return btn;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
```

Also, if you have any general propositions for improvements I'd love to hear them!

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Comment: You're using radius and raidus mixed. I think you need to use raidus inside the drawCircle function.

Comment: @SayedSajadHosseini please do not overwrite other's edits. Always take update before submitting an edit. The snippet I added is removed.